# Porting a Pre 5.7.9 MySQL database to Version 8.0

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to import a MySQL database and its associated entries. I keep getting problems with simply copying the old database folder and trying to convert using `innodb_force_recovery = 0`. It is giving me problems saying it has trouble converting for versions less than 5.7. I have a set of `.frm` files in the old database folder as well as a `db.opt` file. I also have the old `ib_logfile0`, `ib_logfile1` and and `ib_data1` files. Is there some way for me to import my old database into the newer MySQL?

Here is the log I get when I simply copy over the files:

```
2019-03-01T11:00:54.514854Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] D:\mysql-8.0.15\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.15) starting as process 6152
2019-03-01T11:00:54.608784Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-013090] [InnoDB] Unsupported redo log format (0). The redo log was created before MySQL 5.7.9
2019-03-01T11:00:54.608827Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
2019-03-01T11:00:54.810243Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011013] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine.
2019-03-01T11:00:54.810808Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2019-03-01T11:00:54.823309Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2019-03-01T11:00:54.824368Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] D:\mysql-8.0.15\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.15)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

If I try removing the old `ib_logfile0` and `ib_logfile1` I get the following, a load of these type of lines:

```
2019-03-01T11:04:21.468566Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011971] [InnoDB] Tablespace 'innodb_system' Page [page id: space=0, page number=498] log sequence number 5740975 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 5735982.
2019-03-01T11:04:21.468576Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011972] [InnoDB] Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html for information about forcing recovery.
```

and then:

```
2019-03-01T11:04:22.178122Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-013168] [InnoDB] Cannot upgrade server earlier than 5.7 to 8.0
2019-03-01T11:04:27.326810Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011013] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine.
2019-03-01T11:04:27.327338Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2019-03-01T11:04:29.491301Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2019-03-01T11:04:29.492505Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] D:\mysql-8.0.15\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.15)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

Comment: Is your old db server still up or can you spin up a docker instance with the old version to use `mysqldump`? Or again, you can do intermediary updates on your docker box until you reach to the version you want and then copy the data folder over.

Comment: OK, I will try this, thanks :)